# Ultimate Member Register form not working / Not showing a success message

Tags: wordpress, ultimate-member

I have created a register form and profile form in Ultimate Member plugin where I need to register users in specific user role.

I don’t know why the user can’t register successfully with the register form. When click on the submit button, same page is showing again. Even there is no error showing.

I also tried to deactivate all the plugins and activate them one by one by checking the register form. But still it’s not working. I have also checked with theme’s different versions but still, that’s not worked.

On same website, I created one register form before 3 month, that is working fine and showing profile too. For this form, user role is different but this older one working fine. I have added both profile shortcodes on user page just one after another.

I tried to make a plugin & theme conflict test, but the problem still appears.

I also tried to deactivate all the plugins and activate them one by one by checking the register form. But still it’s not working. I have also checked with theme’s different versions but still, that’s not worked.

Comment: Please refer to Wordpress also in title and in teh first sentence, not only in the labels. And please add more details like Wordpress version. Perhaps some more details, screenshots can be also helpful.